# Overwriting jest.mock for react-router-dom and useHistory hook

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, react-hooks

I have a component that uses the `useHistory` hook.

When I am writing unit test, I mocked the `react-route-dom` module so that the `useHistory` hook will be properly mocked in the component that is being tested.

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useHistory: () => ({
    location: {
      pathname: 'home',
    },
  }),
}));
```

However, in one of the tests (named `testB`), I would like to overwrite the `location.pathname`, such that the `pathname` is of a different value (`help`) from the default mocked value..

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useHistory: () => ({
    location: {
      pathname: '/home',
    },
  }),
}));

describe('testing ComponentA', () => {
   afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
   });

  it('test A', () => {
    // some test
  });

  it('test B', () => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
      useHistory: () => ({
        location: {
          pathname: '/help',
       },
     }),
    }));
    // expect ...
  });

  it('test C', () => {
    // some test
  });
});
```

However, this does not seem to work as intended, as the inner mock does not seem to overwrite the top level mock. May I know how can this be done? I have searched other similar threads, but they do not work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to archive something similar by mocking the `react-router-dom` library in a `__mocks__` folder, and then mocking the hook individually in each test I needed to override it's return value with `mockReturnValue`.

```js
// /__mocks__/react-router-dom.js
module.exports = {
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useLocation: jest.fn(), // --> you may use useHistory instead
};
```

```js
it('Should ...', () => {
  // Here mock what you want to test
  useLocation.mockReturnValue({
      search:"?foo=bar",
  });
       ...
  });
```

In your case using `useHistory` should be something like

```js
it('Should ...', () => {
  // Here mock what you want to test
  useHistory.mockReturnValue({
   location: {
      pathname: '/home',
    },
  });
       ...
  });
```

I'd love to know if anyone has a better approach.

Comment: Life saver answer 